# IN Clause dont work in MySQL for me

Tags: mysql, sql, select, in-clause, find-in-set

I am passing my parameter as 'Suburbun','Indigo' to retrieve records matching both Campaigns in below Stored Procedure created in MySql.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DemoSP`(Campaign VARCHAR(3000))
BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT('Select * from vicidial_log WHERE campaign_id IN (?)');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  SET @CampaignID = Campaign;
  EXECUTE stmt USING @CampaignID;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

It Doesn't give any rows!

But when i pass only 'Suburbun' in SP, it gives 6 Rows!

Where am i going wrong?

--Answer !

I tried as Lee Fentress commented in http://www.poolofthought.com/index.php/2008/12/28/a-comma-seperated-list-as-parameter-to-mysql-stored-procedure/ and peterm answer reflected similar coding,

It worked!

Thanks, but i find this negative mark as compared to SQL Server.

Gee, Thank you Guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use `USING` in this case. You can just build the full query sting and execute it without parameters

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE DemoSP(Campaign VARCHAR(3000))
BEGIN
  SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM vicidial_log WHERE campaign_id IN (', Campaign, ')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Note:** make sure that delimited values that you pass in `Campaign` are properly quoted (like you said they are)  and quotes in values, if there is any, are escaped.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01f6a/1)** demo

Comment: Hey, Peter thanks!!! It Worked. But i came across similar thing(See ,y updated Question). I tried and it worked! And Thanks a lot for SQL Fiddle!! Helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

There is no need to use `PREPARE STATEMENT`. You can get the result using `FIND_IN_SET()` function

```
SELECT * FROM vicidial_log WHERE FIND_IN_SET(campaign_id, Campaign)
```

Comment: @Akash May I know the issue you're facing?

Comment: It just didnt worked! My Statement Select * from vicidial_closer_log WHERE FIND_IN_SET(campaign_id, Campaign) didnt returned any row

Comment: In order for `FIND_IN_SET()` to work delimited values in `Campaign` parameter should be unquoted `'Suburbun,Indigo'`. But the **major** issue with this approach is that it prevents any index from being used effectively causing a full scan every time.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
"Select * from vicidial_log WHERE campaign_id IN ('?')"
```

instead of

```
'Select * from vicidial_log WHERE campaign_id IN (?)'
```

Comment: This won't work - go ahead and try it. Prepared statements don't support variable arrays